# Bootstrap navbar header - how to center the image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've a main layout page that is used on all other pages. The following bootstrap navbar header has an image that always displays on the left. I would like it to display in the center. I've tried to use `<div class="text-center">...</div>` but to no vail. I'm using ASP.NET Core with VS2015 that by default has Bootstrap 3.0 installed and confitured. But this question may be generic to all Bootstrap users:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <table><tr><td><img src="~/images/abc.gif"></td></tr></table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of all the unnecessary containers and add `text-center` to `navbar`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top text-center">
      <img src="~/images/abc.gif">
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ctrppwLe/

P.S You should avoid using tables unless you're presenting tabular data.

Comment: Thank you. It works. In regard to using table, I'm displaying two images horizontally adjacent to each other. so, I used a table. But per your suggestion, I removed the table and just placed the two img tags adjacent to each other and images are displaying fine, at least, in  Chrome.